# How to use google fonts locally instead of importing in angular 4 project

Tags: angular, sass, google-fonts

I am importing google fonts urls in my angular 4 project scss file like below,

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,600,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo:400,500,700');
```

instead of importing url's directly, how can I download/install them and use locally in angular 4 scss file.

Any solutions will be helpful.

Answer (score 15):

2 step solution

> Step - 1 : **Download** the fonts and **save** them inside **assets** folder

Save the ttf/otf file inside the assets folder of your project

> Step - 2 : In your **css file**, just **import** them with proper relative path

```
@font-face {
  font-family: lato;
  src: url(assets/font/Lato.otf) format("opentype");
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, although I would recommend using only the woff font format if you don't need to support extremely old browsers. Here is how: http://davidensinger.com/2014/10/update-your-font-face-file-formats-to-just-use-woff-and-woff2/

Answer (score 3):

Download Google’s style sheet hosted on `googleapis.com` domain:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700&display=swap
```

Save the file right into your theme directory so it’s now:

```
https://www.example.com/themes/fonts.css
```

When you open this `fonts.css` file, there is content which looks like this:

```
/* latin-ext */
 @font-face {
   font-family: 'Montserrat';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-display: swap;
   src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v15/JTUSjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459Wdhyzbi.woff2) format('woff2');
   unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
 }
...
```

Save font from `url` in newly created folder `fonts` in your theme and replace path in `fonts.css` so it’s:

```
src: url(https://www.example.com/themes/fonts/JTUSjIg1_i6t8kCHKm459Wdhyzbi.woff2) format('woff2');
```

NOTE: In my case, there were 60+ fonts to download :-)

Last step is to add `fonts.css` to your HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="local-fonts-css" href="https://www.example.com/themes/fonts.css?ver=1.0" type="text/css" media="all">
```

That's the basic. More details in [this](https://www.jasom.net/host-google-fonts-locally-in-wordpress-theme/) blog post.